# How to use shared Preference values in Viewmodel

Tags: android

I'm saving value of the current `locale` into `SharedPreferences`,

viewmodel's data should be changed by current `locale`, so I have to use `SharedPreferences`..

```
private fun getPreferences(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
}
```

this code needs `context` , I don't know how can I use `SharedPreferences` in `Viewmodel`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewModel class should be extend by AndroidViewModel.

after that call getApplication() and use it as context when accessing SharedPreferences.

```
public class YourViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

   SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("pref_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   String varName = sharedpreferences.getString("var_name", "")

}
```